# Email each new workbook of a split workbook

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have code that splits a workbook based on a condition. I want to email each of those new workbooks to different people.

When I run the macro, it splits the workbook and puts all the worksheets where I want them. When I try to send I only send 1 email.

```
Sub savesheetsSend()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Filetype As String
Dim Filenum As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Dim open_book As Workbook
Set outmail = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outmsg = outmail.createitem(0)

Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook

'create directory to save each sheet in
FolderName = "C:\Users\jpenn\Desktop" & "\" & wb.Name
MkDir FolderName

On Error Resume Next

'save each sheet as workbook in directory
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    If ws.Range("A1") = 1 Then
        Filetype = ".xlsm": Filenum = 52
        ws.Copy
        xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & Filetype
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=Filenum
    End If
Next

'send all new workbooks to email address in CELL("B1")
For Each open_book In Application.Workbooks
    If open_book.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

        With outmsg
            .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " payroll data"
            .To = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b1").Value
            .body = "I will get to this later"
            .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .send
        End With
    open_book.Close
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Send the attachment while you are on the 1st for each ws, right next to save as

Comment: Move `Set outmsg = outmail.createitem(0)` just before `With outmsg` in your loop

Comment: .Attachments.Add(xFile)

Comment: Not entirely sure which one made it work but I did all three AND changed the .subject/.to to open_book instead of Activebook, and it now runs, 

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way... Tested

```
Option Explicit
Sub savesheetsSend()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filetype As String
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim Filenum As Long
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Open_Book As Workbook
    Dim OutMsg As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutMail = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set Wb = Application.ThisWorkbook

    'create directory to save each sheet in
    FolderName = "C:\Users\jpenn\Desktop" & "\" & Wb.Name
    MkDir FolderName

    'save each sheet as workbook in directory
    For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets

        If Ws.Range("A1") = 1 Then
            Filetype = ".xlsm": Filenum = 52
            Ws.Copy
            xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & Filetype
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=Filenum

            Set OutMsg = OutMail.createitem(0)

            With OutMsg
                .Subject = Ws.Name & " payroll data"
                .To = ActiveSheet.Range("b1").Value
                .Body = "I will get to this later"
                .Attachments.Add (xFile)
                .Display
            End With

            ActiveWorkbook.Close

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!, this is cleaner than mine with only one loop and perfect, thanks for the help.